# Can we split and separate a box which holds a particle in spatial superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Question 1: Can a particle in an isolated box be in an equal superposition of "located in the LEFT half of the box" and "located in the RIGHT half of the box"? If yes, then:

Question 2: Would it be possible, in principle, to carefully insert two walls dividing the box in the middle, and then bring the resulting two half-boxes e.g. 1 meter away from each other, in a way that the particle inside remains in a spatial superposition?

Comment: A physical system that is related but not identical would be a particle in a double-well potential, if you vary the parameters of the potential appropriately. These have been experimentally realized, eg https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.74.053612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you search for the term 'Quantum Szilard engine' you will find a number of papers explaining how it can be done.